# Help with rise and run of a graph that scales logarithmically

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, slope

[Bode Plot where the x domain is a scales my decade (log10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOg0f.png)

Hi guys i am just lost regarding this graph. I need to find the point $w<100$ where the graph starts to rise and the point $w>5000$ where the plot stops to fall. The x axis scales by decade like $10^0, 10^1, 10, 10^2$

Comment: What does 'dec' mean in $40$ dB/dec? And what is the point between $0 < \omega < 1000$ at which the graph starts to rise?

Comment: Indeed, the slope of the line is a big hint on this one. How many "decs" do we have to go down from 30 db (with the slope 40 db/dec) to reach 0 db? Use a similar approach to the second part.

Comment: Yes I am having trouble with the decade interval. Like let's say the graph start to fall at $w = 20$ at the rate of 20 db/decade. What would be the value of $w$ if at the negative 20db point assuming the graph is initially zero

Comment: So starting at $(\omega=20, dB=0)$, you need to go exactly one decade (if the rate is -20 dB/decade) to get to -20 dB, that should be clear. So what number is exactly one decade above $\omega=20$? Perhaps $\omega  = 10\cdot 20 = 200 $. Do you agree with this logic?

Comment: Yes thank you it helped a lot! :D